# What is the best way to launch either Google Maps or Apple maps with an existing KML file from your iOS app?

Tags: ios, google-maps, kml, apple-maps

The situation: 
I'm writing an app that uses a lot of GPS data as part of its core functionality. In my iOS app, I'm downloading some kml files from our backend/S3. That is all working fine. I have the filepath of the downloaded kml file available on the device.

I need a way to launch either Google Maps or Apple maps with this kml file data from my app (either using `UIApplication.shared.open(...` method for google maps, or `mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)`, or similar).

I'm writing in Swift.

I haven't seen much recent documentation on how to do this, either from Google or Apple Maps. Any ideas?